# Create CSV file through PHP which will be readable in Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv, character-encoding

I am creating a CSV file which containts special characters.
So I set it to UTF-8 in order to display those characters.

The problem is, in Excel all data is displayed in a single column.
It ignores the separator.

```
public static function exportCSV($month) {
        $file = fopen("../export/test_csv.csv","w");
        fputs($file, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
        $header = 'Beløb;Valørdato;Status';
        fputcsv($file,explode(';',$header), ';');
        fclose($file);
    }
```

The file is generated, I can read it with no issue in Libre Office.
But I need to make it working in Excel.

The special characters are displayed, but they are all in one column. Is it possible to separate them by tabs?

Desired result should be:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
Beløb       Valørdato   Status
```

I have read a solution here saying if you use '/t' it will do the job. But it doesn't seem to work, maybe I did something wrong? I used /t instead of ; but no luck

Can anyone please help me with this?

**EDIT:**
I just managed to fix this thanks to RiggsFolly
I separated the values within $header with , (comma)

Then in fputcsv function I added t as a separator and it worked ;)

```
fputcsv($file,explode("\t",$header), "\t");
```

Comment: A comma separated value file is the same no matter which programm you are using to read it.
The problem with Microsoft Excel is that you HAVE to tell which character is the value separator when you open or import the CSV file.
That's not something you can solve with a different programming approach or a different data structure.

Comment: Hello, so basically there is no solution to this? Doesn't excel have some kind of default separator so that when someone opens the CSV, to automatically display the content correctly without the need of choosing additional options etc?

Comment: Have you tried using a COMMA as the seperator in this Comma Seperated Value file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I used comma and they work fine now.